# Changing user password in PgAdmin on mac

Tags: r, postgresql, pgadmin

I am using gAdmin on mac. So far I have not been able to figure out how to run the desktop version, so I am running the web application. I want to change the password for the user `postres`. The reason being, I am trying to connect R to postres using:

```
db <- 'dvdrental'  #provide the name of your db
host_db <- "localhost"
db_port <- '5432'  
db_user <- "postgres"  
db_password <- " " # I typed the master password in, as I do not remember setting up this user/password

con<-dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), dbname = db, host=host_db, port=db_port, user=db_user, password=db_password)
```

but I keep getting below error:

`Error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres".`

This is thee reason for the change of password for the user `postgres`
**How can I change a user password in PgAmin4  using webapp on mac?**

Comment: If the password is wrong when using R, why isn't it also wrong while starting up PgAdmin4?  Or you using a different user in PgAdmin4 than you are in R?  Are you sure you are connecting to the same server in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

In PgAdmin4, if you are changing the password for the same user you are logged in as, then you need to select a connected database from the browser tree.  Once you do that, the "Object" menu "Change Password..." option.

If you are logged into the server as a super user and want to change the password of a different user/role, then right click (or whatever mac uses for that function) on that user/role from the tree and choose "Properties...".  Then under the "definition" tab there is a place to enter the new password.  Note that this method is inferior, as the password is received by the server as plain text (once any ssl decryption is done) and so can end up in the log file in the clear.

Why constrain yourself to PgAdmin4?  `psql` has `\password`, which does this better.